# Force one Task to be selected always in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

We are currently moving our old batch-scripts to Inno Setup installers.

We are facing the problem that our users can skip the task page by selecting nothing.

How can we say the tasks page that one (but only one) option has to be selected?

Thanks for your input! :)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`exclusive` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=taskssection&anchor=exclusive) to force (only) one task to be selected always:

```
[Tasks]
Name: one; Description: "Option one"; Flags: exclusive
Name: two; Description: "Option two"; Flags: exclusive unchecked
Name: three; Description: "Option three"; Flags: exclusive unchecked
```

[image]

Comment: When i add "unchecked" to every componetnt but the first,

*[Components]
Name: "SM_C34H890"; Description: "C34H890"; Flags: exclusive
Name: "HP_Z24n"; Description: "Z24n"; Flags: exclusive unchecked*
I get **"Parameter "Flags" includes an unknown flag."**

Comment: oops, my bad, sorry, i mixed something on my todo list (vacation is bad^^)

Comment: The "only select one" is fixed, thanks :)
Now it would be nice if the page is empty when the user comes to it so a click on *Next* isn't possible..

Comment: If you have a different question, post it separately (with more explanation, as I'm not sure from your comment what you actually need).